# EXCEL: How to count if data matches in specific columns where header is within the date range?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I would like to get a count on the total number of lessons of a specific length given within a specific date range.

I can figure out how to get the number of a specific type of lesson on a specific day with something like in:

```
=countifs(INDEX($E:$V,,MATCH($A8,$E$1:$V$1,1)),"=30")
```

But I can't figure out how to to find all of the values for say Dates <=A8 (for row 8), or dates >A8 & <=A9 (for row 9).

I am looking to get the data to output like the yellow section.

[image: Example Sheet]

Comment: You example is on Google Sheets.  How to do this in Excel will be totally different than how to do this with Google Sheets.  Which one are you using.

Comment: Yes, I am using google sheets just for the mock-up the actual file is excel.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel:

```
 =countifs(INDEX($E:$V,,MATCH($A8,$E$1:$V$1,1)):INDEX($E:$V,,IFERROR(MATCH($A9,$E$1:$V$1,1)-1,COLUMN($V$1))),"=30")
```

But note, this will not work in Google Sheets.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make some adjustments since it was double counting on dates that were listed for instance January 10th. So I created a hidden column for and used =SUMPRODUCT() to calculate the days between the date and then modified your formula to use that for the first date rather than the date above. I will post the solution below.

Comment: the `-1` on the `MATCH($A9,$E$1:$V$1,1)-1` should have taken care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the most elegant. My solution was to create a hidden column (Now E:E) for the to calculate the days between the A column dates.

Example for cell E9

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$W$1>A8)*($F$1:$W$1<A9))
```

This returned a number of days between days A7 and A8.

I then modified Scott Craner's formula to this (Example for cell B9):

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX($F:$W,,MATCH($A9-$E9,$F$1:$W$1,1)):INDEX($F:$W,,IFERROR(MATCH($A9,$F$1:$W$1,),COLUMN($W$1))),"=30")
```

Remember now, that after adding a column my dates shifted from E1:V1 to F1:W1

These two steps solved my issue with double counting on certain dates.

Lastly, I went back and tested this with Google Sheets and it does now appear that it will also work with Google Sheets.